# Referencing a statement with quantifiers in two separate lines

Tags: logic, notation, terminology, first-order-logic, article-writing

I want to show that a statement with several quantifiers, e.g., "$f(a, b) <= 0$ for all $a\in [0, 3]$ and all $b\in [-\infty, -1]$", is equivalent to another statement  with several quantifiers, e.g., "$g(a, b) <= 0$ for all $a \in[-10, 15]$ and $b < 0$", where $f$ and $g$ are two functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, although this is irrelevant to my question.

When it comes to writing that they are equivalent and, more specifically, when referencing the first statement, I'm not sure how to do it.

**Which option of the two below is most frequent in mathematical writing?**

### OPTION 1

Line 1: We have shown that

Line 2: $f(a,b) <=0$                   **Eq.(1)**

Line 3: for all $a\in[0,3]$ and all $b\in[-\infty,-1]$.

Line 4: Now we will prove Eq.(1) is equivalent to the *condition* $g(a,b)<=0$ for all $a\in[-10,15]$ and $b<0$.

---

Eq.(1) above refers just to “$f(a,b)<=0$" and doesn’t include the quantifiers “for all $a\in[0,3]$ and all $b\in[-\infty,-1]$”. Therefore, I wonder if Line 4 can be interpreted as “Now we will prove $f(a,b)<=0$ is equivalent to the condition $g(a,b)<=0$ for all $a\in[-10,15]$ and $b<0$”, which clearly is not what I want to show.

### OPTION 2

To address this potential issue, I guess the solution would be as follows:

Line 1: We have shown that

Line 2: $f(a, b) <= 0$ for all $a\in [0, 3]$ and all $b\in [-\infty, -1]$.    **Eq.(1)**

Line 3: Now we will prove Eq.(1) is equivalent to the *condition* $g(a,b)<=0$ for all $a\in[-10,15]$ and $b<0$.

---

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I wonder whether I should write "statement" instead of "condition" in Line 4.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking, but maybe this will help. First, we need to say exactly what $f,\,g$ are. In particular, what are the domains of $f$ and $g$? My guess is that $f:{\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:{\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R,$ and you want to show that "for all $(a,b) \in [0,3] \times (-\infty, -1]$ we have $f(a,b) \leq 0$" IF AND ONLY IF "for all $(a,b) \in [-10,15] \times (-\infty, 0)$ we have $g(a,b) \leq 0$". That is, $f$ is non-positive throughout a certain region of the plane iff $g$ is non-positive throughout another region of the plane.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: All details you mention are irrelevant for my question. Say, within a proof, you have a statement with quantifiers, e.g., an inequality followed by several "for alls" (this statement is an intermediate result within the proof). And you want to show this statement is equivalent to a statement consisting in another inequality + several quantifiers. o do so, I need to cite the first statement so I have to create a label (e.g., Eq.(1)). Should I include the quantifiers in Eq.(1) or should just write the inequality in Eq.(1) but followed by the quantifiers in a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style will guide writers on such issues. This is a Question about math writing & you can check out Style guides , eg Knuth or American Mathematical Society or other alternatives.

**Here is how I might have written it :**

---

We have shown Proposition P1 :
$\forall a \in [0,3] , \forall b \in [-\infty,-1] : f(a,b) \leq 0 \tag{P1}$
Now we will prove P1 is equivalent to Proposition P2 :
$\forall a \in [-10,15] , b \le 0 : g(a,b) \leq 0 \tag{P2}$

---

**High-light :**

Use Math Symbols like $\forall$ & $\exists$ rather than "for all" & "there exists"

Use Math Symbols like $\leq$ & $\geq$ rather than "<=" & ">="

Prefer words like Corollary & Proposition & Lemma & Theorem for Conclusions & use words like Condition & Criteria within those Conclusions.

Use "tags" to refer later.

### UPDATE :

When we do not want to make Propositions & it is in the flow of some argument , then this tweak can work :

---

We have shown that :
$\forall a \in [0,3] , \forall b \in [-\infty,-1] : f(a,b) \leq 0 \tag{7}$
Now we will prove that (7) is equivalent to the following :
$\forall a \in [-10,15] , b \le 0 : g(a,b) \leq 0 \tag{8}$
We use (8) to get our Core result (9) like this :
$\cdots$

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I meant referencing an intermediate result (e.g., the first statement above) within a proof (I don't have two propositions, as in your answer). That is, I have a statement I derived within a proof, for which I created the label Eq.(1) for posterior referencing. Then, I wonder how to reference it. Should I include the quantifiers in Eq.(1) or should just write the inequality (see example above) in Eq.(1) but followed by the quantifiers in a separate line (that is, "outside Eq.(1)")?

Comment: I have updated , @Ruth , request you to recheck.

Comment: Is there still some concern with my answer , @Ruth , maybe something not resolved yet ?

Comment: Fully resolved! My very last doubt is whether to use "condition" or "statement" here: Now we will prove Eq.(1) is equivalent to the condition/statement (,)<=0 for all ∈[−10,15] and <0. Thank you

Comment: You could use Statement/Expression/Condition/Property , @Ruth , or even make it "unnamed" number. Ideally , when your Question gets resolved , then you should indicate that with "accepting" some answer , though "upvoting" is entirely optional.